# how to connect an embedded device to bluetooth chat application in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth hardware device ( embedded one ) that is acting as a client and connecting with pairing permissions automatically to any device whose bluetooth is ON. But it is not connecting to the BT chat application installed on my android phone.  The BT chat application works fine when it connects to my hardware device as a slave. But in case of my hardware device acting as a client and BT chat acting as a listening server, connection fails. 
Does the AcceptThread code works only on application level and not on system level?
The hardware device connects my android phone at system level but not to bluetooth chat application.
Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth chat app basically supports only classic bluetooth.
Please check the bluetooth profile of your embedded device. Does your embedded device supports classic bluetooth?

Comment: my device supports both SPP ( serial port profile ) and classic one

Comment: Ok I somehow got it connected but now connection between my android app and that hardware device lasts for few seconds ( 3 secs ) and after that it throws an "disconnected , IOException : java.io.IOException: Software caused connection abort"

Comment: Also both exchange some data in 3 seconds, but after that they get disconnected.

Comment: are you connecting using BluetoothGatt?

Comment: if you are using BluetoothGatt, then confirm there is not any password set on your embedded  device.

Comment: no I am not using BluetoothGatt and there's not any password set on my embedded device.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your chat application is using createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord().
Use the createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord instead. Insecure socket allows the RFCOMM to communicate with a non-authenticated paired device. Embedded devices like the RN42 or KC2114 have a difficult time performing authenticated pairing, because user interaction is required (numeric comparison, yes-no response). The "Just Works" automatic pairing will not produce an authenticated pairing. KC2114 supports both automatic authenticated pairing (with a small hack) and Just Works non-authenticated pairing.

Comment: my chat application is using createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord. But does this part help in Server side code of bluetooth chat?